# PyKafka offset commits

Tags: python, python-2.7, kafka-python

I am using the below script to read message from a Kafka topic. I am able to read messages. However, the offset does not commit. Any advice for how to force the offset to commit, or anything that may presently prevent committing? (Note: This is basically taken from the documentation, you can see it is very similar to their balanced consumer example.)

I am using Python 2.7.8, pykafka 2.1.1, and kafka 0.8.2.1.

Thank you.

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient(hosts='myHost:9092')
topic = client.topics['myTopic']

balanced_consumer = topic.get_balanced_consumer(
    reset_offset_on_start=False,
    consumer_group='myTestConsumerGroup',
    auto_commit_enable=True,
    auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
    zookeeper_connect='myZookeeperHost')

for message in balanced_consumer:
    if message is not None:
        print(str(message.offset) + '\t' + message.value)
    balanced_consumer.commit_offset()
```

Comment: How have you verified that the offsets are not being successfully committed? If this is still an issue, I recommend testing with pykafka 2.5.0